# Best way to count set bits in Oracle

Tags: oracle, binary

In order to save space for a very particular use-case in Oracle SQL, I'm experimenting with using a bitmap methodology for representing Boolean state over time (an event did or did not happen on that day), with each bit in a binary number representing yes/no for that day. That way, for example, a 32 bit number would allow me to represent 32 consecutive days of whether something happened each day. I would simply need to count the number of bits that are set (=1) to get the count of days in that 32-day period that the event occurred, without having store a separate dated row for each day.

Here's an example of me testing updating the value each day (rolling off the oldest bit and setting the newest one):

```
SELECT testbitmap original_bitmap,
       BITAND((testbitmap * POWER(2,/*rolloff the nbr of days since last event*/1)) + /*the event happened today*/1,POWER(2,32)-1) new_bitmap
  FROM (SELECT BIN_TO_NUM(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) testbitmap
          FROM dual)
```

So far so good. But now I need to query the result, and that means counting the set bits of my resulting bitmap. There isn't an inverse of `BIN_TO_NUM` that I know of in Oracle. Without using a function that loops through each bit and tests it individually, **is there a way to count set bits in Oracle** (e.g. the number 9 should result in 2 (`1001`), whereas the number 7 would result in 3 (`0111`)? Maybe a mathematical formula the returns the number of 1s required to represent a number in binary?

Comment: Your request is quite uncommon. I think you have to loop over the bits (and you would also need to do it in almost any other programming language). Be aware, many function are limited to 2**32. If you have more days, then you may get wrong results.

Comment: How much space do you plan to save? Unless your table has billions of rows, the difference should be negligible.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit, I'm thinking over a year, so maybe 48 bytes (max 384 days). Versus an IOT child table with a 7-byte date + avg 8 bytes for a 11-digit numeric surrogate key + 1 byte row overhead * 365 = 5,840 bytes. A regular table would require much more with the necessary index. Whatever my data volume is, the bitmap method uses less than 1/100th of the amount of space (48 bytes vs 5840 bytes). And yes, we are talking billions of rows. I have 16 billion entities that will get tracked this way.

Comment: There are some decent algorithms that are better than just looping over the bits, but nothing out-of-the-box in Oracle.  You'd have to implement one of them yourself.  I suggest you give back a little of that space savings are precompute and save the number of set bits whenever you insert or update each bitmap.

Comment: Some of those algorithms are explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/266304). You could also consider a Java stored procedure that uses `bitCount`.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth mentioning that Oracle does have a built-in function that does exactly what you want - [BITMAP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/BITMAP_COUNT.html#GUID-F1A3261E-7DA9-4FEF-8413-E38907C856BA). Unfortunately, the function only works with a bitmap generated in Oracle's proprietary BLOB format, which is very large and inconvenient to use. So it likely isn't something you want to seriously consider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Hamming Weight algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/109025/1509264), in C++ it would be:

> ```c++
> int numberOfSetBits(uint32_t i)
> {
>      // Java: use int, and use >>> instead of >>. Or use Integer.bitCount()
>      // C or C++: use uint32_t
>      i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);        // add pairs of bits
>      i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);  // quads
>      i = (i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;        // groups of 8
>      return (i * 0x01010101) >> 24;          // horizontal sum of bytes
> }
> ```

In Oracle, you can use the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION number_of_set_bits32(
  i NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v NUMBER := i;
  c_max CONSTANT NUMBER := POWER(2, 32);
BEGIN
  v := v - BITAND(TRUNC(v/2), TO_NUMBER('55555555', 'XXXXXXXX'));
  v := MOD(
         BITAND(v, TO_NUMBER('33333333', 'XXXXXXXX'))
         + BITAND(TRUNC(v/4), TO_NUMBER('33333333', 'XXXXXXXX')),
         c_max
       );
  v := BITAND(v + FLOOR(v/16), TO_NUMBER('0F0F0F0F', 'XXXXXXXX'));
  RETURN TRUNC(MOD(v * TO_NUMBER('01010101', 'XXXXXXXX'), c_max) / POWER(2, 24));
END;
/
```

Then to count your value would be:

```sql
SELECT testbitmap AS original_bitmap,
       NUMBER_OF_SET_BITS32(testbitmap)
FROM   (
  SELECT BIN_TO_NUM(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
           AS testbitmap
  FROM   DUAL
)
```

Which outputs:

| ORIGINAL_BITMAP | NUMBER_OF_SET_BITS32(TESTBITMAP) |
| --- | --- |
| 3429605376 | 11 |

---

You should also be able to create an Oracle function using Java:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_set_bits(i NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'java.lang.Long.bitCount( long ) return long';
/
```

Which, for the same `SELECT` query, gives the same output.

---

#### 64- and 128-bit Numbers:

If you want a 64-bit (or 128) function then double (quadruple) the width of all the hex-strings and change the final divide from 2<sup>24</sup> to 2<sup>56</sup> (2<sup>120</sup>), to get the top 8-bits, as mentioned in the answer linked at the top of this answer:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION number_of_set_bits64(
  i NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v NUMBER := i;
  c_max CONSTANT NUMBER := POWER(2, 64);
BEGIN
  v := v - BITAND(TRUNC(v/2), TO_NUMBER('5555555555555555', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
  v := MOD(
         BITAND(v, TO_NUMBER('3333333333333333', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'))
         + BITAND(TRUNC(v/4), TO_NUMBER('3333333333333333', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')),
         c_max
       );
  v := BITAND(v + FLOOR(v/16), TO_NUMBER('0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
  RETURN TRUNC(
    MOD(v * TO_NUMBER('0101010101010101', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), c_max)
    / POWER(2, 56)
  );
END;
/
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION number_of_set_bits128(
  i NUMBER
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v NUMBER := i;
  c_max CONSTANT NUMBER := POWER(2, 128);
BEGIN
  v := v - BITAND(TRUNC(v/2), TO_NUMBER('55555555555555555555555555555555', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
  v := MOD(
         BITAND(v, TO_NUMBER('33333333333333333333333333333333', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'))
         + BITAND(TRUNC(v/4), TO_NUMBER('33333333333333333333333333333333', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')),
         c_max
       );
  v := BITAND(v + FLOOR(v/16), TO_NUMBER('0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'));
  RETURN TRUNC(
    MOD(v * TO_NUMBER('01010101010101010101010101010101', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), c_max)
    / POWER(2, 120)
  );
END;
/
```

Or, in Java, for larger numbers you can use `java.math.BigInteger.bitCount()`:

```sql
CREATE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED bitutils AS
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class BitUtils {
  public static Integer bitCount(
    final BigDecimal value
  )
  {
    return value == null ? null : value.toBigInteger().bitCount();
  }
};
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_set_bits_java(i NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'BitUtils.bitCount( java.math.BigDecimal ) return java.lang.Integer';
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2dyvT8IP)

Comment: Thank you. I accepted this answer but also posted another one of my own that you might be interested in. I appreciate the quick and helpful response!

Comment: @PaulW I've added a 64-bit version of the function. The link at the top of the answer includes a section "How this SWAR bithack works" which explains how/why the function works in plenty of detail (and has a section on the adaptions for the 64-bit version).

Comment: @PaulW I've also added a PL/SQL version and a Java version that both handle 128-bit numbers.

Comment: thank you for this. I've tested the new 128 bit version and find it matches the output of what I had written with the subtraction/bitand loop method, but where the bit count is significant outperforms it noticeably. I'll be using your algorithm, after all. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I am not as smart as @MT0, I would use this approach. First convert the number into binary:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Dec2Base(DecN IN NUMBER, Base IN INTEGER DEFAULT 16) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS
    
    n NUMBER;
    BaseString VARCHAR2(129) := NULL;
    DecNumber NUMBER := DecN;
    HexString CONSTANT CHAR(16) := '0123456789ABCDEF';
    
BEGIN
    IF DecN IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSIF Base > 16 THEN 
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    ELSIF base = 16 THEN
        RETURN TO_CHAR(DecN, 'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    ELSE
        IF DecN > 2**127 THEN
            -- "MOD(DecNumber, Base)" returns wrong result for larger numbers
            RAISE NUMERIC_OVERFLOW;
        END IF;         
        LOOP
            BaseString := SUBSTR(HexString, MOD(DecNumber, Base) + 1, 1 ) || BaseString;
            DecNumber := TRUNC(DecNumber / Base);
            EXIT WHEN DecNumber = 0;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN BaseString;
    END IF;
    
END Dec2Base;
```

Then you can count the `1` with [REGEXP_COUNT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_COUNT.html)

```
REGEXP_COUNT(Dec2Base(BIN_TO_NUM(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 2), '1')
```

I assume the Hamming Weight algorithm will be more efficient. You may consider to store the value as `RAW` rather than as an integer value. The `UTL_RAW` package provides various functions which should support your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea, from [Count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer/109915#109915) which is quite easy to understand. Written in PL/SQL it's simply:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_count_setbits (in_number IN number)
    RETURN number DETERMINISTIC
  AS
    var_count pls_integer := 0;
    var_number number := in_number;
  BEGIN
    WHILE var_number > 0
    LOOP
      var_count := var_count + 1;
      var_number := BITAND(var_number, var_number - 1);
    END LOOP;
    
    RETURN var_count;
  END;
```

Test output:

```
SELECT test_number,
       f_count_setbits(test_number) nbr_of_set_bits
  FROM (SELECT LEVEL test_number
          FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 16)

1   1
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   2
6   2
7   3
8   1
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  2
13  3
14  3
15  4

SELECT /* 32 bit */ f_count_setbits(BIN_TO_NUM(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)) FROM dual

11

SELECT /* 127 bit */ f_count_setbits(BIN_TO_NUM(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)) FROM dual

44
```

While this does loop, it doesn't loop for every bit... only for every set bit (1). Therefore a number with sparse bits (few 1s) will loop very few times. This makes it good for use at tracking sparse events.

However, in actual implementation with large numbers, especially after MT0 enhanced the Hamming Weight algorithm to support 128 bit numbers, I find that the Hamming Weight approach is still significantly faster.

Comment: @MT0 I found the link and added it.